# javascript websocket connection failing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

When I run the following in jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/W5ARu/1/) on one machine it works, but on another it doesn't.  What gives?

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://html5rocks.websocket.org/echo',['soap', 'xmpp']);
```

The error on the machine where it doesn't work is

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://html5rocks.websocket.org/echo' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: Status line contains embedded null

It's strange because I started off my journey with this problems trying to use a simple karma runner or node-inspector without success.  Also, I'm seing this in my Chrome, Safari, and Canary.

Answer (score 0):

Lame, looks like it was my accountability software x3watch.